# How to Implement B2B Orders with Location-based Payment Terms using Shopify's Mobile Buy SDK

Tags: ios, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node, shopify-mobile-buy-sdk

I am currently developing a B2B native mobile app (iOS and Android) that interfaces with a Shopify store. This application serves companies that have multiple locations, with each location having its own unique payment terms such as card payments or term checkout.

So far, I have been able to leverage Shopify's Mobile Buy SDK to authenticate a customer, display products, and manage the checkout process. Here's an example of the current implementation in Swift:

```
let client = Graph.Client(shopDomain: "my-shop-name.myshopify.com", apiKey: "your-api-key")
let customerInput = Storefront.CustomerAccessTokenCreateInput(email: "user@example.com", password: "password")

let mutation = Storefront.buildMutation { $0
    .customerAccessTokenCreate(input: customerInput) { $0
        .customerAccessToken { $0
            .accessToken()
            .expiresAt()
        }
        .userErrors { $0
            .field()
            .message()
        }
    }
}
```

However, the next step is proving to be a challenge. I need to incorporate additional B2B features, allowing a logged-in user to:

1. Select their associated company location,
2. Fetch the payment method relevant to the selected location, and
3. Use the fetched payment method for checkout.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find built-in support for this in the Mobile Buy SDK. Is there a direct way to handle these B2B features using the SDK, or will I need to devise a workaround or custom implementation?

In the case that I need a workaround, what would be the best practice for this? Are there other platforms or APIs better suited for implementing such B2B functionalities in a mobile app?

I've tried finding a solution in the documentation and on forums